# Dataflow Flex template job is Queued

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am trying to reproduce [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) to run a Flex Template on Dataflow.

When I submit the job, I can see it in the console but it's not started and marked as **Queued**. Does this mean that the job is submitted in a [FlexRS mode](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/flexrs) ? How can I start directly the job after submitting it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, where an upstream dependency (pyarrow?) started requiring `git` in order to build, but the base image does not currently include `git`.  I have filed an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176570473

Answer (score 5):

The "Queued" status for Flex Template jobs means that your container is running on a VM to build the pipeline and start the job.  If the job stays in Queued for more than a few minutes, that indicates the this process got stuck.  You can view the logs for this VM in the Dataflow UI in the "Job Logs" section.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, so the job have failed and when I checked the job logs as you suggest I found this : 
 `Output from execution of subprocess: .....  OSError: \'git\' was not found\n ----------------------------------------\nERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`

Comment: Looks like your container doesn't contain all of the dependencies it needs in order to start the job.  In this case, you'll just need to add a line to your dockerfile "RUN apt-get install git"